# Raspberry Pi - Raspberry OS - Telegram-CLI

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, debian, telegram

I need help to install a telegram CLI on my Raspberry Pi. There are many instructions but no one works

e.g.:

1. `install libreadline-dev libconfig-dev libssl-dev lua5.2 liblua5.2-dev libevent-dev libjansson-dev libpython-dev make lua-lgi git`
2. `cd /usr/local/src`
3. `git clone --recursive https://github.com/vysheng/tg.git && cd tg`
4. `./configure`
5. `make`

Output:

```
gcc -I. -I. -I./tgl -g -O2  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/lua5.2  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-omit-frame-pointer -ggdb -Wno-unused-parameter -fPIC -iquote ./tgl/tl-parser -c -MP -MD -MF dep/tl-parser.d -MQ objs/tl-parser.o -o objs/tl-parser.o tgl/tl-parser/tl-parser.c

tgl/tl-parser/tl-parser.c: In function ‘tl_parse_args134’:

tgl/tl-parser/tl-parser.c:1907:26: error:bash: oot@raspberrypi:/usr/local/src/tg#: No such file or directory

 ‘sprintf’ may write a terminating nul past the end of the destination [-Werror=format-overflow=]

sprintf (s, "%lld", lrand48 () * (1ll << 32) + lrand48 ());
                          ^
tgl/tl-parser/tl-parser.c:1907:9: note: ‘sprintf’ output between 2 and 21 bytes into a destination of size 20

         sprintf (s, "%lld", lrand48 () * (1ll << 32) + lrand48 ());

         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [Makefile.tl-parser:4: objs/tl-parser.o] Error 1
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I follow following link:

https://github.com/vysheng/tg/issues/1610

```
sudo nano /tg/Makefile
```

remove option -Werror

after this:

```
sudo nano tgl/mtproto-utils.c
```

Go to line 101

Add // at the begin (comment)

Write it ([ctrl]+X)

redo make

This works for me!